# Adding different json_data.ajax.success handlers for different node types in Jstree

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jstree

I want to represent a tree-structure using [Jstree](http://www.jstree.com). I am facing the problem that the server does not returns the data in a jstree-compliant format - it's just ordinary Json.

One solution that I implemented is to use the [`json_data.ajax.success`](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data) callback to modify the data in order to bring it to the required format. However, this function does not get context information - therefore, I don't know what node is being loaded and don't know how I have to transform the received data.

I have seen that there is a [`types`](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/types) plugin that allows different behaviour between nodes - for example, displaying a corresponding icon. Is it possible to use this plugin to add different ajax-success-handlers for each node type? If not, what other solutions are there?

```
$("#tree").jstree({
    "plugins": ["json_data", "themes", "types"],
    "json_data": {
        "ajax": {
            "url": function (n) {   // want to make this type-dependent.
                if (n === -1) {
                    return "...";
                } else if ( ... ) {
                    return "...";
                }
            },
            "success": function (data) {    // want to make this type-dependent
                var result = [];
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    "data": "......",
                    "attr": {
                        "id": ".................",
                        "rel":  "..............."
                    }
                });
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why cannot you change what the server returns?

Comment: I need context information in order to know what type of data is returned by the server and how I have to change the returned data.

Comment: I don't understand, could you elaborate bit more?

Comment: @Radek: Let's say that we have A-nodes and B-nodes in the tree. Depending on the type of the node, the result from the server looks very different and needs different treatment. Because I don't know in the "success" handler what type the node had, and the type cannot be deduced from the server's response, I want to know if there is a way to get context information about which node is currently processed.

Comment: `the type cannot be deduced from the server's response` so how can it be found out?

Comment: @Radek: From the information stored in the node's "attr" values. For example, if you have a directory structure with a depth of one, you know that every descendant of a folder-node is a leaf-node.

Answer (score 1):

You can create json data for jsTree on a server site and then process it one more time on the server to add whatever attributes for jsTree and then you can use types plugin.

Comment: I am looking for a client-only solution. Server cannot be changed, sorry :-) Also don't want to add an additional server component.

Comment: However, the approach would work :-) So giving you a +1 because of your time investment and multiple comments .

Comment: If jsTree can do it you can do it too. I don't know right now how though. Why cannot you change server side?